# How to modify url when language changes

Tags: php, localization

I have a multilangual website in 2 languages english and fr when user changes the language to the en I want to change `/fr/messages/111` to the `/messages/111` for the english language.I use `changeLang.php` page to change the language passing the language(fr or en) 
I tried some ways but sometimes it causes redirect loops is there a method or an easy way to change the url acorrding to the language

Comment: Why don't you keep it in the URL? That way, your viewers can change the language at their discretion, they will have a clear idea of what's going on, and most importantly, from a SEO perspective it's the better thing to do.

Comment: if i keep i still need to change the url when language changes

Comment: That's what hyperlinks and URL parameters are for.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having separate URLs for each language, consider having the same URL return either English or French text depending on the user's preference.  Browsers send an HTTP header called `Accept-Language` that tells you the user's preferred language, and your application can use that to decide which text to send in its response.

This has the advantage that it works automatically, right from the beginning.  The user doesn't have to do anything on your site to choose a language, because the user's browser should be configured to request the correct language by default (based on the OS locale).

Comment: Im trying to learn web programming i have seen websites  change languages that way so i wonder how to do it

Comment: The `Accept-Language` header should only be used for language detection, but visitors should (read: must) be given an option to change the language based on their preference.